# Angular e2e: automatically match chromedriver and chrome versions?

Tags: angular, selenium-webdriver, protractor, selenium-chromedriver, e2e-testing

So, ChromeDriver version again upgraded to 84 version and my chrome is still on version 83, without any update available (probably because I upgraded my Linux Mint to 20). This produces good old:

```
session not created: This version of ChromeDriver only supports Chrome version 84
```

We already know how to fix this and, as usual, to run e2e tests I need to downgrade ChromeDriver version with a workaround:

```
"pree2e": "node ./node_modules/protractor/bin/webdriver-manager update --gecko=false --versions.chrome '83.0.4103.116-1'",
"e2e": "ng e2e --webdriver-update=false"
```

and then run `npm run e2e` for it to work.
Is there a way to automatically force ChromeDrive to match Chrome version? Like writing a `pree2e` script that checks current chrome version and then forces `ChromeDriver` to same one?

Comment: You could try doing a webdriver-manager clean everytime before running your webdriver-manager update with the chrome flags. That should ensure that any other existing version removed before installing the new ones.

Comment: @SankalanParajuli i'm not sure this would help to automatically sync ChroeDriver version to Chrome version. It would only remove newest ones, but when installing it would re-download them

Comment: Chrome always downloads the latest version. The only way to sync this is to specify the version you want downloaded. If you are running this test in a docker container, you can install the require chrome version by doing a `wget https://dl.google.com/linux/direct/google-chrome-stable_current_amd64.deb` and then unpacking and installing it. But when chrome releases the latest version, automatically the latest version is not picked up. If you want to auto sync this, you will have to always download the latest version of chrome available as soon as a release is made. Maybe a hook would do.